# Postfix файл main.cf

Tags: postfix

скажите пожалуйста myhostname и mydomain как задавать...по умолчанию они mail.example.com и example.com.

ну мне какие ставить то:?

Answer (score 1):

Сам с этим долго мучался, решение было найдено методом проб и ошибок, т.е. оно наверняка не очень грамотное.

/etc/hostname -> kite
/etc/hosts, первая строчка -> 127.0.0.1 kite.mysupersite.name localhost kite

main.cf:
mydomain = mysupersite.name
myhostname = kite.$mydomain

mydomain - домен, на котором располагается сервак
myhostname - FQDN, который должен точно указывать на машину, на которой стоит постфикс, причем, если не изменяет память, он должен резолвиться через hosts, а сабдомен должен совпадать с hostname.

Comment: а если нету у меня сайта я просто тестю почтовый сервер то что я могу указать

Comment: @darcon57, простите, тут я ничего не смогу сказать, я ненастоящий сварщик ( По идее должен быть способ настроить на прием по айпи, но я в эту сторону не копал.

Comment: наверное мне надо всё таки мучать линуксоидов..эх..ох уж этот linux

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть свой зарегистрированный домен, то указывайте его и там и там.

```
myhostname = your.domain.com
mydomain = $myhostname
```

Если у вас его нету, то указывайте вместо него `localhost`
Ну и, соответственно, не ожидайте что почту посланную от такого сервера хоть кто-нибудь примет кроме локальных пользователей.